# Does air move faster between rooms with higher temperature differences?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, flow, air

A pair of rooms at an identical temperature.
A pair of rooms where one is very hot and the other very cold.

Does air move faster between one pair of rooms than the other? If it does, is that what creates wind?

Comment: How are the two connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressure differences cause wind. If one room has lower pressure than another, then air will flow from the region of higher pressure to that of lower pressure.

But, temperature has an affect on pressure. If both rooms have the same volume (and particle number),  and if one room has a higher temperature, this would mean it has a higher pressure, in which case the same would be true, and air will flow from it, to the other cooler room.

Comment: No, it does not imply higher pressure unless you also posit matching number of particles

Answer (score 1):

If there is an open door or opening between the rooms so that there is unimpeded air flow, then as warmer air is less dense it will flow through the upper part of the opening while cooler air flows through the bottom of the opening. Air will be exchanged this way even if there are no fans or other means of circulation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a limiting case when the temperature difference is huge.  You'll get a vortex, which is essentially what a tornado is (albeit oriented differently).

On the other end, if both rooms are at the same temperature and pressure (*and* have the same ratios of constituent atomic specie),  all you'll get is the usual Brownian motion of atom and molecular diffusion. Which is to say, no average "wind."